# Is there any way to make a card container size square using CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

Here you can see that the height of these cards height is dependent on the image inside it. I want them to be square regardless of image dimensions i.e. card container should be in square format then we can use image object-fit:cover, I have used aspect-ratio:1 property but it Doesn't work everywhere as it's in experimental stage. [Click here to see the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGzet.jpg)

```css
.card-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card {
  aspect-ratio: 1; // property is in experimental stage, doesn't work everywhere
}

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

`

Comment: Maybe if you wrote : `aspect-ratio: 1/1;` the value would have been applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resort to the old trick of setting padding-bottom to 100% and height 0, this ensures the item is square because padding is created using the width rather than height of an element.

In this snippet he images have different aspect ratios and natural sizes so you can see that it works for any combination of these.

```css
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 20vw;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.card img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/400/300"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/400/400"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/300"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300"></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have setted the `object-fit` opt incorrectly.

Try `object-fit: contain;` to fix the issue.

Comment: object-fit: contain will not work, those image dimensions inside cards are not fixed, it can in rectangle or square what I want the card in square shape, anything out of the card will be hidden.

Comment: Try using a static `width` and `height`? That may works

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. You can take a look at it. Uses `grid` property but instead of using `aspect-ratio` you can replicate it with the help of pseudo classes. Added comments where necessary. Let me know if any part of it require explanation. I have used images from picsum and they are not exactly square so you can be assured it works no matter the image dimension.

**Edit:** Since the minimum value for each column is 200px, taking grid gap into account, after approximately 450px or so, you may get a single column grid. But if you want a double grid for devices below that screen size, you can reduce the `minmax()` value to something like `minmax(100px, 1fr)` via media query accoringly for the parent container.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));/* not explicit repeat, adjusts to screen size based on minmax() */
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.container div {
    display: grid;
    background: black;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

/* results in squared div no matter the screen sizes*/
.container > div::before {
    content: "";
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    display: block;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
}

/* place image on top of :before */
.container > div::before, img {
    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1025/4951/3301.jpg?hmac=_aGh5AtoOChip_iaMo8ZvvytfEojcgqbCH7dzaz-H8Y" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935.jpg?hmac=3N43cQcvTE8NItexePvXvYBrAoGbRssNMpuvuWlwMKg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000.jpg?hmac=aHjb0fRa1t14DTIEBcoC12c5rAXOSwnVlaA5ujxPQ0I" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1010/5184/3456.jpg?hmac=7SE0MNAloXpJXDxio2nvoshUx9roGIJ_5pZej6qdxXs" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1035/5854/3903.jpg?hmac=DV0AS2MyjW6ddofvSIU9TVjj1kewfh7J3WEOvflY8TM" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1032/2880/1800.jpg?hmac=5SLBdyPZBMyr5IBkIRfffZV10bP87Y7RrxVZX1vCefA" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey Dorji, thanks for the info, it's working perfectly for landscape media, but for portrait those properties are not working.

Comment: Can you specify the properties that are not working so that I can have better understand it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72920522/13761333 I've replace one landscape image to portrait, check the difference. It's taking height reference of that image which has the largest height.

Comment: Will take a look at it and let you know!

Comment: I  added two styles and updated the answer, `position: relative;` for container div of image and `position: absolute;` to the image to force the image to size of the container.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));/* not explicit repeat, adjusts to screen size based on minmax() */
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.container div {
    display: grid;
    background: black;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

/* results in squared div no matter the screen sizes*/
.container > div::before {
    content: "";
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    display: block;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
}

/* place image on top of :before */
.container > div::before, img {
    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1025/4951/3301.jpg?hmac=_aGh5AtoOChip_iaMo8ZvvytfEojcgqbCH7dzaz-H8Y" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935.jpg?hmac=3N43cQcvTE8NItexePvXvYBrAoGbRssNMpuvuWlwMKg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000.jpg?hmac=aHjb0fRa1t14DTIEBcoC12c5rAXOSwnVlaA5ujxPQ0I" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1010/5184/3456.jpg?hmac=7SE0MNAloXpJXDxio2nvoshUx9roGIJ_5pZej6qdxXs" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518173946687-a4c8892bbd9f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8bmF0dXJlfGVufDB8MXwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1032/2880/1800.jpg?hmac=5SLBdyPZBMyr5IBkIRfffZV10bP87Y7RrxVZX1vCefA" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).